# MYSQL multiple like search for locations

Tags: php, mysql

I have a large database with over *310 k* rows. Each row has the fields :

Country
Region
City

Here is my query - I am using php pdo to query my properties db :

```
$sql =  'SELECT * FROM properties 
          WHERE ( Country = "'.$searchString.'" OR Region = "'.$searchString.'" 
                  OR City = "'.$searchString.'") LIMIT 100';
$stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
```

Now all though this works fine but I know it is messy and resource intensive can anyone explain to me a cleaner faster way of doing this also Indexes confuse me with mysql, should I set an index up for the three columns and what kind of index would you advise.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: Hi jens, I am actually using prepared statements in my live code, sorry I should of mentioned that I just left them out in my example

Answer (score 0):

Indexes are not going to help, as you have written the query.  You could write add an index on `properties(Country, Region, City)` and use a query like this:

```
select p.*
from properties p
where country = @searchString
union all
select p.*
from properties p
where region = @searchString and country <> @searchString
union all
select p.*
from properties p
where city = @searchString and region <> @searchString and country <> @searchString;
```

This might help, but often an `or` query returns so many rows that indexes are not particularly helpful.